# rails .order desc not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

It is very wierd that the order is working in local but when i push it to heroku its not displaying the correct order

```
<% @address.address.cases.order(due_date: :desc).where.not(invoice_file_name: nil).last(10).each do |d|  %> 

        <ul id="inv"><p><%= link_to d.invoice.url do %>
         <li> <%= d.pt_first_name.capitalize %> <%= d.pt_last_name.capitalize %></li>
        <% end %></p></ul>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details? What do those records look like? How did you check that the sorting is not working? Is `due_date` an optional or mandatory attribute? Do you use the same database engines and the same versions locally and on production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the reason is the `last` method is forces the ascending order. Take a look at your logs. You should see something similar:

```sql
ORDER BY `cases`.`due_date` ASC LIMIT 10
```

To fix this I'd use the `limit` method:

```rb
@address.address.cases.order(due_date: :desc).where.not(invoice_file_name: nil).limit(10)
```

It uses the proper order:

```sql
ORDER BY `cases`.`due_date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But how could this lead to different sorting locally and on production? Shouldn't this still return the same (unexpected) sorting on both environments?

Comment: Maybe there are different datasets in Heroku and locally, or `due_date` just the same across all the records. It's hard to guess without additional details.